# ¿Cómo establecer protected $connection de un paquete que se encuentra en el directorio vendor?

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Instalé el paquete `codebyray/laravel-review-rateable` para calificar los productos de una tienda. Todo está bien, el problema radica en que cuando hago `php artisan migrate` la tabla se guarda en la base de datos principal y no la quiero en esa sino en otra ya que uso varias bases de datos y quiero seguir mi orden.

Sé que si entro al directorio donde está el paquete instalado y busco el modelo puedo agregar mi conexión, pero sé que al reinstalar el paquete perderé los cambios.

¿Existe alguna forma de crear un modelo donde pueda crear mi conexión y el resto de parámetros del modelo sigan en el paquete original?

Comment: Creo que te equivocas en el planteamiento y que `$connection` no está como propiedad protegida de ese paquete. Cuando trabajas con varias bases de datos debes indicar la base de datos que quieres en la configuración de migraciones en un directorio propio y luego usar el [modificador `--path`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations). En los scripts debes elegir explícitamente cuál usar al establecer la conexión `DB::connection('la de votaciones')`.

Comment: Si compartes el archivo de migración y el archivo de configuración que te indica @franmost podremos ayudarte con más detalle con la manera de proceder.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones, la primera y mas enredada es clonar el paquete para hacerte un fork propio y poder modificiarlo y posteriormente añadirlo como repositorio manual a tu composer, dado que sino se borrara en el próximo update.

Y la que mas te recomiendo y mas fácil, crea un modelo igual y haz que extienda del modelo del paquete y así heredara todas sus propiedades y podrás modificarlo aun si se actualiza sin perder cambios.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Tu segunda opción es en la que decidí trabajar mientras.